# How can I expose services from kubernetes cluster to external network to make them available using DNS?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service

I want to expose service to external network with use DNS. For example I have service `my-service` and I want to expose it as `my-service.my-cluster.com`.

1. Should I use some proxy (like nginx ...) or Kubernetes support this?
2. Is DNS should be configured manually or there is some automation.

I assume use it to development and production later - maybe different methods is better for both use case.

For example I want to expose this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: my-service
  name: my-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-service
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking of an http service, you should use an [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/):

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-service-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: your-ingress-controller-class-name
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /your-root
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Basically, an Ingress Controller exposes itself at a Service of type LoadBalancer and creates name-based virtual hosts for each ingress it finds.

Automatic DNS provisioning can be achieved via [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns) – under certain circumstances. Namely if you use a supported DNS provider and a compatible ingress controller (most are).